# Selecting a network switch for basic VLAN use to segment logical networks

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I want to change my small office networking setup to use VLANs. Currently all users are on the same network with different group users sitting in the same room. I thought VLAN would be just the cure I need.

On reading on VLANs, I understood the basic concept. My question concerns connecting different VLAN switches. It appears that these are to be connected using "trunk ports" on the switches. I can find lots of switches which support VLAN but I am not able to find one which specifically states that one of the ports can be configured to be a "trunk port".

I bought a basic Netgear GS108Ev3. It certainly does not have any configuration to enable one port to be used as a "trunk port" to be connected to another switch. Are "aggregating ports" the same as "trunk port" for connecting switches? I am not looking at this time for reliability, fallback port, etc. Can you recommend some basic switches (from any vendor) to get me started to have same VLANs spread across multiple switches where end-devices are connected to "access ports". Once I am comfortable setting a VLAN with two or three switches, primarily to logically segment networks, I will explore other advanced features.

Comment: **I thought VLAN would be just the cure I need** - Cure for what?

Comment: @joeqwerty Cure for basic security so that users from one group are at least from a network perspective separated from users from another group. Also, broadcast will be limited to specific VLANs as opposed to all on the same network.

Comment: To improve your question: cure for correct behaviour of a large network in face of broadcast storms or internal attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any switch with VLAN support will have trunking capability. Trunk ports are used to pass traffic from all vlans between switches. Multiple layer 2 switches will  be configured so that the port(s) that connects them, and the port(s) that connects them to a layer 3 switch or router is a trunk port.

Trunk an aggregated ports are not the same thing. Aggregated ports are groups of ports that act as a single logical unit, allowing aggregation of the bandwith of multiple physical switchports.

You may need to configure the vlans on each switch you connect if they do not support vlan trunking protocol (VTP).

The following Netgear Knowledgebase article describes how to do this on a netgear switch using their browser configuration utility.[KB Article](https://kb.netgear.com/11673/How-do-I-setup-a-VLAN-trunk-link-between-two-NETGEAR-switches)

Comment: To improve your answer: • a trunk port is a port which will transport multiple VLANs, • aggregated ports is a port group which will behave as a uniq port, to add their physical bandwidth, for example 2 1 Gbit/s port will be aggregated to make a virtual port of 2 Gbit/s between 2 important switches.

Comment: @MesaOptimizer The link KB Article was very useful. The basic Netgear VLAN switch I have (GS108Ev3) does not have any option to make a port a T type. However, it allows me to assign the same port to multiple VLANs. I presume that implicitly makes that a trunk port. Is that so? I do not have multiple VLAN switches to try this. dan's answer above also defines a trunk port as one "which will transport multiple VLANs" so it is not necessary for switches to expressly have a mechanism to have a port be made trunk-type? If so, I will buy one more of the Netgear switch I already have and try VLANs.

Comment: @dan Please view my comment above and respond if you can. Thanks

Comment: @Sunny My experience in this is limited to Cisco hardware and cisco only allows a single access vlan per switchport and the switchport mode is either access or trunk. I had some difficulty finding better information on the Netgear site and because of this I don't have a confident answer. It seems to me if it will allow you to tag a single port with every vlan then that port will act as a trunk but I have not been able to find documentation to back up this belief.

Comment: @MesaOptimizer Thanks. I will try after I get another Netgear switch.

Answer (score 0):

"Trunk" is an overloaded phrase: it can mean either a port that carries multiple/all VLANs, or it can mean link aggregation where multiple ports are tied together to form a single logical link.

Cisco uses the former terminology, and the way to form an uplink port that carries all VLANs there is to just set the port mode to "trunk" (as opposed to "access" for normal user ports). Some others use other terminology, and may require you to explicitly tick all VLANs you want to carry in a port. [Netgear's manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS105EV2/WebManagedSwitches_UM_EN.pdf) looks like it goes in the latter group (chapter 3, starting at page 28).

So, for uplink ports, add the port to each VLAN that you want to pass in the port (or the VLAN to the port). The manual looks like they have some simplified way of configuring VLANs as an alternative to the full 802.1Q support. If it asks, make sure to mark the ports/VLANs as "untagged" for your normal user ports, and as "tagged" for uplink ports.

Tagging here refers to the actual VLAN tag that's added to the Ethernet frame transferred on the wire. An untagged frame is just a normal frame, while a tagged one has a few extra bytes prepended to it that tell which VLAN the frame belongs to. Your usual computer would expect to see just untagged frames. On uplinks (or any link that carries multiple VLANs), tags are needed to tell the VLANs apart.